# Defining variables inside an "eval" function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***Given a makefile:***

```make
# We force Make to execute commands, both for 'x' and for 'all'.
$(shell rm -rf x all)

# The "global" variable 'foo'
foo = global

# The target-specific variable 'foo', defined for target 'x'.
x : foo = target

all: x
    @echo '$@: "$(foo)"'

x :
    $(eval foo += 1)
    @echo '$@: "$(foo)"'
```

***And running, I get:***

```console
$ make
x: "target"
all: "target 1"
```

If you look closely, we have here 2 different variables with the name `foo`:

1. The *global* one.
2. The *target-specific* variable, defined for the target `x`.

As you can see, the variable `foo` was expanded twice, first in the context of target `x`, which of-course refers to the *target-specific* variable, and then in the context of the target `all`, which must be the **global** variable, as `all` has no *target-specific* variable `foo`.

But, the *global* `foo` had the value `global`, how then it is expanded to `target 1`?

More so, for the target `x`, we appended the value `1` to a variable (which variable was it? The *global*? The *target-specific* one?). As it seems, this *append* had no effect whatsoever on the *target-specific* variable, as evident in the next command line for 'x', where `foo` is expanded to plain `target`. No `1` is appended here.

But, by this reasoning, we assume that the `eval` in the recipe for `x` target, referred to the *global* variable, so it should had appended to the existing **global** value, which is `global`, and not to the *target-specific* variable `target`.

But, looking at the expansion of the `foo` target, in the execution of the recipe for target `all`, we see that the **global** variable has the value `target 1`, which looks like the *append* was done on the *target-specific* variable.

Which contradicts the previous assumption, that was based on the output of the recipe for target `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me you have to consider **read** and **write** actions when accessing variables in a target with `eval` and *target-specific* environment. So for an `eval` statement in a target it seems that:

- A **read** access to a variable refer to the *target-specific* one.
- A **write** access to a variable refer to the *global* one.

---

And you can re analyse your code this way:

```make
# The global variable 'foo'
foo = global

# The target-specific variable 'foo', defined for target 'x'
x : foo = target

all: x
    @echo '$@: "$(foo)"'
#                 ^
#                 global as there is no target-specific for 'all'

x :
    $(eval foo               = foo + 1)
#          ^                   ^
#          write: global       read: target-specific
    @echo '$@: "$(foo)"'
#                 ^
#                 read: target-specific
```

Finally, we can say:

- The *target-specific* variable have not been changed in the `x` target
- The *global* variable have been changed by the `x` target. The new value is `<target-specific value> + 1`
- As `x` is a prerequisite of `all`, the *global* variable will always been changed before running the `all` target

---

To conclude, try this `Makefile`:

```make
foo = global

x: foo = x
y: foo = y

all: x y
        @echo '$@: "$(foo)"'

x y:
        $(eval foo += 1)
        @echo '$@: "$(foo)"'

.PHONY: all x y
```

And you will get:

```console
$ make
x: "x"
y: "y"
all: "y 1"
$ make y all
y: "y"
x: "x"
all: "x 1"
```